# Stash Branch permission via REST API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to set branch permission in Stash using the REST API, unfortunately i didn't find anything on the documentation [page](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html)

I want to set a master branch and assign 2 users to it (Admins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The branch permissions API is part of a separate (though bundled) plugin, so the documentation is in a different place, [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-branch-permissions-rest.html)